# How to use a provider inside of another provider in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create an app that has an `authentication service` with different permissions and functions (e.g. messages) depending on the user role.

So I created one `Provider` for the user and login management and another one for the messages the user can see.

Now, I want to fetch the messages (once) when the user logs in. In `Widgets`, I can access the Provider via `Provider.of<T>(context)` and I guess that's a kind of `Singleton`. But how can I access it from another class (in this case another Provider)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks for your answer. In the meanwhile, I solved it with another solution:

In the `main.dart` file I now use `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider` instead of `ChangeNotifierProvider` for the depending provider:

```
// main.dart
return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => Auth()),
        ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Messages>(
          builder: (context, auth, previousMessages) => Messages(auth),
          initialBuilder: (BuildContext context) => Messages(null),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        ...
      ),
    );
```

Now the Messages provider will be rebuilt when the login state changes and gets passed the Auth Provider:

```
class Messages extends ChangeNotifier {
    final Auth _authProvider;

    List<Message> _messages = [];
    List<Message> get messages => _messages;

    Messages(this._authProvider) {
        if (this._authProvider != null) {
            if (_authProvider.loggedIn) fetchMessages();
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Adding to that, here is an article that explains all `Provider`s - https://medium.com/flutter-community/making-sense-all-of-those-flutter-providers-e842e18f45dd

Comment: Hi, how would you solve if you have to perform some async task in update. Like naybe setting user properties by fetching from server after getting user id.

Comment: This will reset the state in `Messages`. Take a look at another answer here on how to keep the Messages state using an `builder: (...) => Messages..update(previousMessages)` https://stackoverflow.com/a/67535632/5552686

Answer (score 31):

From **version >=4.0.0**, we need to do this a little differently from what @updatestage has answered.

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (_) => Auth()),
    ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Messages>(
      update: (context, auth, previousMessages) => Messages(auth),
      create: (BuildContext context) => Messages(null),
    ),
  ],
  child: MaterialApp(
    ...
  ),
);
```

Comment: The `create` is actually optional, so you don't have to specify it.

Comment: @user1032613 it is not optional anymore for `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider`, but for `ProxyProvider`.

Comment: @WSBT **No, it's required** as you can see from `required Create<R> create,`. This is also true in its other forms such as `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider2()`, `ChangeNotifierProxyProvider3`, etc.

Comment: @enchance You might be necro-posting to an old comment... software evolves over time, and we are no longer at version 4.

Answer (score 15):

Passing another provider in the constructor of the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider may cause you losing the state, in that case you should try the following.

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<MyModel, MyChangeNotifier>(
  create: (_) => MyChangeNotifier(),
  update: (_, myModel, myNotifier) => myNotifier
    ..update(myModel),
);
```

```
class MyChangeNotifier with ChangeNotifier {
  MyModel _myModel;

  void update(MyModel myModel) {
    _myModel = myModel;
  }
}
```

Comment: I should have read your comment before implementing the above solutions. I wasted like 4 hrs trying to figure out why state was being lost

Answer (score 3):

It's simple: the first Provider provides an instance of a class, for example: `LoginManager`. The other Provides `MessageFetcher`. In `MessageFetcher`, whatever method you have, just add the `Context` parameter to it and call it by providing a fresh context.

Perhaps your code could look something like this:

```
MessageFetcher messageFetcher = Provider.of<ValueNotifier<MessageFetcher>>(context).value;
String message = await messageFetcher.fetchMessage(context);
```

And in `MessageFetcher` you can have:

```
class MessageFetcher {
  Future<String> fetchMessage(BuildContext context) {
    LoginManager loginManager = Provider.of<ValueNotifier<LoginManager>>(context).value;
    loginManager.ensureLoggedIn();
    ///...
  }
}
```

Comment: So instead of DI through the constructor, you do it through `Provider.of`?

Comment: Yes it's one of the ways to access the provider. It is never done through the constructor AFAIK. context.watch or context.read are new ways to do the same thing. Another option is the Consumer widget.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like this would be a lot easier with Riverpod, especially the idea of passing a parameter into a `.family` builder to use the provider class as a cookie cutter for many different versions.