# How to add Dependency Injection in Flutter with Provider

Tags: flutter, dart, dependency-injection, architecture, provider

```
void main() => runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) => QuoteViewModel(),
      ),
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (BuildContext context) => AuthorViewModel(),
      ),
    ], child: MyApp()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Poems',
      home: PoemsListPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
class QuoteListPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _QuoteListPageState createState() => _QuoteListPageState();
}

class _QuoteListPageState extends State<QuoteListPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final model = Provider.of<QuoteViewModel>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Poems List')),
      body: _buildBody(model.getQuotes()),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildBody(List<Quote> quotes) => ListView(
        children: quotes
            .map((quote) => ListTile(
                  title: Text(quote.body),
                ))
            .toList(),
      );
}
```

quoteListPage.dart

```
class Quote {
  final String id;
  final String authorId;
  final String body;

  Quote(this.id, this.authorId, this.body);
}

class Author {
  final String id;
  final String name;

  Author(this.id, this.name);
}
```

models.dart

```
class Repository {
  final Api _api = Api();
  final Database _database = Api();

  List<Quote> getQuotes() => [];

  List<Author> getAuthors() => [];
}
```

repository.dart

```
class QuoteViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final Repository _repository = Repository();

  List<Quote> getQuotes() => _repository.getQuotes();
}

class AuthorViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final Repository _repository = Repository();

  List<Author> getAuthors() => _repository.getAuthors();
}
```

notifiers.dart

#### I had tried using **ProxyProvider** after reading an article on [Medium](https://medium.com/jet-set-digital/architecture-components-flutter-ft-restful-api-sqlite-dependency-injection-4b872463981a) but it ends with the error  "This is likely a mistake, as provider will not automatically update dependents"

```
List<SingleChildWidget> globalProviders = [
  Provider.value(value: Api()),
  Provider.value(value: Database()),
  ProxyProvider2<Api, Database, Repository>(
    update: (_, api, database, __) => Repository(api, database),
  ),
  ProxyProvider<Repository, QuoteViewModel>(
    update: (_, repo, __) => QuoteViewModel(repo),
  ),
  ProxyProvider<Repository, AuthorViewModel>(
    update: (_, repo, __) => AuthorViewModel(repo),
  )
];

void main() => runApp(
      MultiProvider(
        providers: globalProviders,
        child: MyApp(),
      ),
    );
```

main.dart (updated)

```
class Repository {
  final Api _api;
  final Database _database;

  Repository({@required api, @required database})
      : _api = api,
        _database = database;

  List<Quote> getQuotes() => [];

  List<Author> getAuthors() => [];
}
```

repository.dart(Updated)

```
class QuoteViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final Repository _repository;

  QuoteViewModel({@required repository}) : _repository = repository;

  List<Quote> getQuotes() => _repository.getQuotes();
}

class AuthorViewModel with ChangeNotifier {
  final Repository _repository;

  AuthorViewModel({@required repository}) : _repository = repository;

  List<Author> getAuthors() => _repository.getAuthors();
}
```

notifiers.dart(Updated)

Comment: It will be helpful for others, if you could give only the problematic code rather than than all the code from your project. That way people can just focus on your problem and need not have to scroll through hundreds of lines to find the faulty code

Comment: Found solutions on this? I'm also searching for ways how to provide the change notifier with it's dependency through an Multiprovider.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57765994/how-to-use-a-provider-inside-of-another-provider-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has a guide on using the provider package that could help you out. https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple It'll be helpful if you could be more specific with the issue that you're having with provider.